# Como Armazenar dados em Tabelas Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Criei um shiny bem simples que era simplesmente para um "controle de estoque".Tem uma tabela que inicia com seus produtos(colunas) no valor zero. O objetivo era toda vez que clicar no botão de ação 1 ele aumentasse o estoque, por exemplo tem uma caixa numérica e foi posto o valor 5 nela o programa pegaria o valor anterior da tabela, no caso o 0, e somaria com o 5. Se o usuária repetisse o clique seria os 5 que  já tinham mais os 5 da caixa numérica. Porém, o valor não é armazenado. Quando clico no botão ele sempre faz a soma 0 (valor inicial) mais o valor da caixa de texto, se clicar de novo ele não armazena o valor anterior e faz novamente a soma 0 mais o valor da caixa numérica. Gostaria de saber como posso resolver, ou seja como posso armazenar uma variável com o botão de ação. Código:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("Entrada dos Chops"),
      numericInput("Chop1","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      numericInput("Chop2","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      numericInput("Chop3","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      numericInput("Chop4","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      numericInput("Chop5","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      actionButton("Botao1","Adcionar chop!",icon("ice-cream",lib="font-awesome")),
      h1(" "),
      h1("Venda dos Chops"),
      numericInput("Chop6","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      numericInput("Chop7","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      numericInput("Chop8","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      numericInput("Chop9","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      numericInput("Chop10","Sabor 1",min = 0,max = 100, value = 0),
      actionButton("Botao2","Vender chop!",icon("ice-cream",lib="font-awesome"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h1("Tabela estoque chops"),
      tableOutput("SaidaTabela")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 isolate({ 
  Chopp1=0
  Chopp2=0
  Chopp3=0
  Chopp4=0
  Chopp5=0

  Tabela=data.frame(Chopp1,Chopp2,Chopp3,Chopp4,Chopp5)

  output$SaidaTabela=renderTable(Tabela)
 })

  observeEvent(input$Botao1,{
               Tabela[1,1]=Tabela[1,1]+input$Chop1
               Tabela[1,2]=Tabela[1,2]+input$Chop2
               Tabela[1,3]=Tabela[1,3]+input$Chop3
               Tabela[1,4]=Tabela[1,4]+input$Chop4
               Tabela[1,5]=Tabela[1,5]+input$Chop5
               output$SaidaTabela=renderTable(Tabela)


                              }

               )

  observeEvent(input$Botao2,{
               Tabela[1,1]=Tabela[1,1]-input$Chop6
               Tabela[1,2]=Tabela[1,2]-input$Chop7
               Tabela[1,3]=Tabela[1,3]-input$Chop8
               Tabela[1,4]=Tabela[1,4]-input$Chop9
               Tabela[1,5]=Tabela[1,5]-input$Chop10
               output$SaidaTabela=renderTable(Tabela)


               }

  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: O comum nesse tipo de caso é criar uma variável que vai sendo alterada. Para criar essa variável veja `?shiny::reactiveValues()`

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples e suja, porém eficaz, é  colocar um comando `save()` para salvar um .Rdata e lê-lo no preâmbulo.